# Javascript compiler / compactor (Windows GUI)

Tags: javascript, windows, compiler-construction

I need to compile / compact an "ever-growing" javascript app (round abouts 40k LoC, currently).

I don't have the time to integrate the "appropriate" tool for what I'm trying to do, something like **require.js**, as it requires modification of said code.

I was planning to just manually pile everything together to do a compact/compile routine, but at this point, I think that will make it quite difficult to maintain. (Ultimately, I'd like to keep the file structure broken down into its current hierarchy.)

That being said, I've been using a tool called [Winless](http://www.winless.org) for .less compilation, andI really like its functionality:

- add a folder set
- note the files you want to include
- watch for changes in those files and recompile when that happens

I'm wondering if an analogous tool exists for js?

The [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) does a top notch job, and I hear that [Uglifyjs](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl//uglifyjs) is good too. I might end up using Closure's REST api to manually manage file sets, but I'm wondering if anything exists that abstracts the process a little bit -  into a **standalone windows gui**?

I've been poking around for a couple weeks, but have not come up with anything solid.

Cheers -

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this link may help: http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/

Comment: For JS I'd say [GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com/) is all you need. Also, love the terminal, it's just quicker, faster, more convenient than a GUI for automating things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://gruntjs.com/ - "The JavaScript Task Runner". It becomes dead easy to script tasks, which would be along the lines of

a) run JSHint (for spotting errors in your code)

b) Run any QUnit tests

c) and finally call Uglify.js to compress your source in to a compressed, deployable file (I include a version number in mine to avoid caching issues).

Comment: I'll check this out. This won't work directly with my current dev environment (weird combo of windows, svn and a locked down local NAS box).. but it might be worth modifying for access to this. Looks pretty good.

Comment: Old thread, I've since used Grunt, Gulp, and Webpack extensively. Webpack + Gulp seems to be the current sweet spot. I was never able to track down a gui / tool like winless. CLI FTW.